# How to Determine the Output Shape of a Conv2DTranspose of an AutoEncoder

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, deconvolution

I am building an autoencoder for learning 28 ultrasound time signals of shape [262144,2] i.e. 262144 pairs of time and voltage points concatenated to form a [262144x2] tensor as input data to a stacked convolutional encoder. The latent space is set to produce a vector of length 16. The problem arise from the decoder, where a 'for loop' is used to stack two Conv2DTranspose layers each with a filter sizes of 64 and 32 and a kernel of 3 to the latent space output in order to reproduce the original input shape of [262144x2]. Instead, the decoder network gives a [262144x4] output tensor which does not match the validation and input data shapes of [262144x2]. What model parameters (filter, kernel, strides and padding) should I use to get appropriate tensor dimensions? the code and output are shown below. Your assistance is greatly appreciated!

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten
from keras.layers import Reshape, Conv2DTranspose
from keras.models import Model
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_Train = Signals             
x_Test = Signals1

Sig_size1 = x_Train.shape[1]
Sig_size2 = x_Train.shape[2]

Sig_size11 = x_Test.shape[1]
Sig_size22 = x_Test.shape[2]

x_Train = np.reshape(x_Train,[-1, Sig_size1, Sig_size2, 1])
x_Train = x_Train.astype('float32') / np.max(x_Train)

x_Test = np.reshape(x_Test,[-1, Sig_size11, Sig_size22, 1])
x_Test = x_Test.astype('float32') / np.max(x_Test)

# network parameters# encoder/decoder number of filters per CNN layer
input_shape = (Sig_size1, Sig_size2, 1)
batch_size = 32  # Was 32
kernel_size = 1 # Was 3
latent_dim = 16  # Was 16

# encoder/decoder number of filters per CNN layer
layer_filters = [2, 6]

# build the autoencoder model
# first build the encoder model
inputs = Input(shape=input_shape, name='encoder_input')
x = inputs

# stack of Conv2D(32)-Conv2D(64)
for filters in layer_filters:
    x = Conv2D(filters=filters,
                kernel_size=kernel_size,
                strides=2,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same')(x)

shape = K.int_shape(x)

# generate latent vector
x = Flatten()(x)
latent = Dense(latent_dim, name='latent_vector')(x)

# instantiate encoder model
encoder = Model(inputs, latent, name='encoder')
encoder.summary()
plot_model(encoder, to_file='encoder.png', show_shapes=True)

# build the decoder model
latent_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='decoder_input')

# use the shape (7, 7, 64) that was earlier saved
x = Dense(shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3])(latent_inputs)
# from vector to suitable shape for transposed conv
x = Reshape((shape[1], shape[2], shape[3]))(x)

# stack of Conv2DTranspose(64)-Conv2DTranspose(32)
layer_filters = [1,8]  ########change
kernel_size = 3 # Was 3
# for filters in layer_filters[::-1]:
for filters in layer_filters[::-1]:
    x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=filters,
                        kernel_size=kernel_size,
                        strides=2,
                        activation='relu',
                        padding='same')(x)
    
# layer_filters = [64, 32]
kernel_size = 3 # Was 3
# reconstruct the input
outputs = Conv2DTranspose(filters=1, #Was 1 
kernel_size=kernel_size,
activation='sigmoid',
padding='same',
name='decoder_output')(x)

# instantiate decoder model
decoder = Model(latent_inputs, outputs, name='decoder')
decoder.summary()
plot_model(decoder, to_file='decoder.png', show_shapes=True)

# autoencoder = encoder + decoder
# instantiate autoencoder model
autoencoder = Model(inputs,
decoder(encoder(inputs)),
name='autoencoder')
autoencoder.summary()
plot_model(autoencoder,
to_file='autoencoder.png',
show_shapes=True)

# Mean Square Error (MSE) loss funtion, Adam optimizer
autoencoder.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

# train the autoencoder
autoencoder.fit(x_Train,
x_Train,
validation_data=(x_Test, x_Test),
epochs=1,
batch_size=batch_size)

# predict the autoencoder output from test data
x_decoded = autoencoder.predict(x_Test)
```

This code was adapted from Advanced Deep Learning with Keras by Rowel Atienza (Chapter 3 for a denoising decoder for MNIST data)

Comment: Please past your code as text with proper formatting applied to it. Thx.